# Purchase in a camera shop

Tags: probability

This is a basic probability question.

Suppose that in a camera shop, of all customers who buy cameras, 60% buy a case, 40% buy a tripod and 30% buy a case and tripod. Given a person has bought a camera and case what is the probability that he also purchased a tripod?

Comment: Try drawing a Venn diagram that counts camera-buying customers, assuming there are 100 customers. Among those who bought a case, what percentage bought a tripod?

Comment: I'm curious: Are you the same person who a year ago was asking questions about topological groups and unramified algebraic extensions of local fields?

Answer (score 2):

So you know $P(\text{case}) = .6$ (the probability of a customer buying a case is 60%) and $P(\text{tripod}) = .4$ (the probability of a customer buying a tripod is 40%), and also $P(\text{case AND tripod}) = .3$ (the probability of a customer buying both a case and a tripod is 30%).

Now, you want to find $P(\text{tripod} |  \text{case})$, which is the probability of a customer buying a tripod given he/she bought a case.

Just use this nice formula for the conditional probability (this is how conditional probability is actually defined.  $$P(\text{tripod} | \text{case}) = \dfrac{P(\text{tripod AND case})}{P(\text{case})} $$

Answer (score 1):

$P(case|camera) = 0.6$. $P(tripod|camera) = 0.4$, $P(case, tripod|camera) = 0.3$. What is $P(tripod|case, camera)$?

$P(tripod, case|camera) = P(case|camera) \cdot P(tripod|case, camera)$. Thus the answer is $\frac{0.3}{0.6} = 0.5$.